# How to pass Product keys while installing MS Office using puppet scripting?

Tags: windows, ms-office, puppet

I want to install a word, excel and outlook from full setup of ms office using puppet scripting and also pass the product key from scripts only.

If somone could tell me the command line command to do so would also be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [msoffice](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppet/msoffice) module for puppet. You can provide license key, and define which products you want to install.

E.g from module web page:

```
msoffice { 'office 2010':
  version     => '2010',
  edition     => 'Professional Pro',
  sp          => '1'
  license_key => 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX',
  products    => ['Word,'Excel']
  ensure      => present,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go from a pure package perspective, you can use the built-in provider or the chocolatey provider to do so. You will need an auto unattend xml file, see https://chocolatey.org/packages/Office365HomePremium and download the package (link on the left), rename it to a .zip file and then unzip the contents to see how it is setup.

Definitely another way to go about it (and possibly better) is to use the msoffice module suggested in another answer by @kkamilpl